# When you have two models connected by a foreignkey in django do you need to do a join?

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-key-relationship

The Django docs are not plainly stating this and its getting annoying.

Observe the following models:

```
# models
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgUnique('venueMedia/venueImages'))
    streetAddress= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, related_name='rooms', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    standingCapacity = models.IntegerField
    seatedCapacity = models.IntegerField
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgUnique('venueMedia/venueImages'))
```

I have a foreign key relationship into `Venue` in the `Room` model in the rooms `venue` property.

Do I need to join those tables? Or will a `Venue.objects.all()` do that for me automatically?  If not I have the raw sql as follows will this work:

```
 venueList = Venue.objects.raw('''SELECT *
                              FROM venue_Venue
                              INNER JOIN venue_Room
                              ON venue_Venue_id=venue_Room_id''')
```

if not that then I understand there is a `select_related()` method and my understanding is that I would do the following:

```
Venue.objects.all().select_related('Room')
```

Can we get this clear? As you can see I have done alot of research but am still confused

Comment: venuel.objects.all() will contain the room object.u dont need to write raw query or some thing.for example `venue = Venue.objects.all()` nd if u want get the room name u can use `venue.room.name`..this will work if not let me know

Comment: thanks dude this is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**select_related**

select_related can be used when you want to select the objects connected by ForeignKey or OneToOne field, more precisely you can use this only when you want to select a single connected object. select_related takes a param can use it to lookup for related_field. The param `related_name='rooms'` specified in your model attributes is responsible for setting related names. select_related method searches for these related names and if it finds a match then it returns you the related objects. This line

```
Venue.objects.all().select_related('Room')
```

would result in a lookup error as you don't have any related names 'Room' but you have `room` so you also need to watch out for case sensitivity. Below one would work.

```
Venue.objects.all().select_related('room')
```

As mentioned above select_related can only be used for selecting single related objects. If you wish to fetch multiple related objects like for ManyToManyField then use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: but to be clear I don't need to use select related. As @Abi said above, venue.objects.all() will grab the room object. By what your telling me if I had another model connected to venue say amenities for example but only wanted the room model not both. I would then use select related. I can use select related in this case however but since I only have one connected table, its unnecessary right?

Comment: yeah it would not be necessary to use related_field here but just for the sake of question i tried to explain the related_fields. They can be used in other cases like the one you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you could add that `select_related` is a performance optimization. It does not influence the filtered objects in the queryset, but it does influence what those objects looks like. In SQL terms, it adds the fields of the joined model to the SELECT part of the statement, but doesn't alter the JOIN or WHERE clause.